# How to pipenv install a dependency with Pipfile/Pipfile.lock

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

Say I have the following two local python directories:

```
package
 - Pipfile
 - Pipfile.lock
```

```
lib
 - Pipfile
 - Pipfile.lock
```

Now I want to install `lib` into `package`, so I could import and use `lib`'s functions inside `package`. How do I do that, while respecting `lib`'s `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: Do you want to auto-install the lib's Pipfile or merge the two, or something else?

Comment: @Borisu I want to auto-install the lib's Pipfile